# How do I implement circle image with fade in animation?

Tags: android, listview, animation, fadein

I have list view and I want image views inside every list item to be circle shape. Also I want animate image appearing kind a "fade in" animation.

I have tried this:

```
 private void setImageDrawable(ImageView imageView, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mFadeInBitmap) { // mFadeInBitmap = true;
            BitmapDrawable drawable = null, placeholder = null;
            if (bitmap != null) {
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
                placeholder = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, mPlaceHolderBitmap);
            }
            final TransitionDrawable td =
                    new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                            placeholder,
                            drawable,
                    });

            imageView.setImageDrawable(td);
            td.startTransition(500);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

But this code doesn't work because I have tried to use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) and [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView.) as ImageView. Neither supports TransitionAnimation.

So I'm wonderring is there any simple way to implement circle shape image with fade in animation? How would you do that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 2):

use picasso library for animation and also you can round images and you can store images to catches automatically.

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(mayorShipImageLink).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ImageView);
```

and create java file CircleTransform.java

```
public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

 Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
 if (squaredBitmap != source) {
  source.recycle();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(shader);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

 float r = size / 2f;
 canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

  squaredBitmap.recycle();
  return bitmap;
   }

  @Override
   public String key() {
   return "circle";
   } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Animation to achieve fade-out and fade-in animation create a folder in res->anim and define fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true">
     <alpha
         android:fromAlpha="0.0"
         android:toAlpha="1.0"
         android:duration="1000"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      />
</set>
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true">
     <alpha
         android:fromAlpha="1.0"
         android:toAlpha="0.0"
         android:duration="1000"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      />
</set>
```

And then in your java

```
 Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out);
 imageView.startAnimation(anim);
 final Handler handler=new Handler();

 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_network_wifi_black_48dp);//changing to different image ,here you will set image that you have loaded
        anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
        imageView.startAnimation(anim);
    }

  },1000);
```

Comment: It's great! Thank you @L-X! Just one thing: before images are loaded into list I want to display placeholder instead.  But after invoking your animation placeholder image disappears and animation starts. Is there any way to make fade in from placeholder image to one just loaded?

Comment: Well there's a trick that you can use , So I am assuming you want to animate when you have loaded your image from  server or file . Create two animation.xml file when "fade_out.xml" in which fromAlpha="1.0" and toAlpha="0.0" and in "fade_in.xml"  same as above before setting your final image that you have loaded call fade_out animation and then set your imageView to new image(delay this for 1 sec with the help of Handler class) and call fade_in animation, If you didn't understand ,I can explain with code also

Comment: Explain with a code sample, please, because I never deal with Handler class.

Comment: The duration for fade_out is 1000 millisecond thats why in Handler i have use 1000 to let it wait till animation is complete and then change the image that you want and start fading_in ,I hope its clear

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is simple and works well. I will try to achieve effect exactly as I want but if I don't find it I'll use yours.